# How Can I Make GIMP Zoom In/Out When I Hold CTRL and Scroll My Mouse Wheel?

Tags: gimp, zoom

I am using Gimp on Linux, and everything works great ... except mousewheel zoom.  For some reason that I don't understand, I can't make my mousewheel (when `CTRL` is held down) zoom.

As you can see, it is configured to do so in the Gimp preferences:

[image: Gimp Settings Screenshot]

but no matter what "action" I set, nothing happens.

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you try a different mouse?  I have Gimp 2.1 on Ubuntu with a LogiTech M557 Bluetooth Mouse and Ctrl - Roll works just fine. So it may be your mouse

Comment: I'll try to find another mouse to test with, but it's a perfectly normal USB mouse, and I can zoom in/out just fine in other apps (eg. Chrome), so there's no reason it should have issues.

Comment: Also consider reinstalling Gimp. Uninstall, restart, and install the newest version of Gimp. Also make sure machine mouse and perhaps also BIOS drivers and Linux are all up to date.

Comment: Sadly I already tried that, via Synaptic, but reinstalling didn't help :(  As for the BIOS/drivers, I run updates regularly, and installed a fresh distro last year (and again, this is just a basic USB mouse, nothing fancy), so I'd be truly baffled if there was a driver problem with it ... especially since (again) no other program has any mouse problems of any kind.

Comment: I am not sure. I tried on Ubuntu 20.04, Gimp 2.1 and zoom works. I now just tried Gimp 2.1 on Kali 2020.4 and zoom worked there as well - no issues. I will keep looking around but Gimp is working for me.

Comment: If you have a way to run a Virtual Machine (VBOX should work - I use VMware), set up a brand new test Linux machine of a common distribution, install Gimp 2.10 and see if the mouse works that way.